# GridViewMultiComboBoxColumn: Allow User to Enter Data

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik, multiple-columns, combobox

I got a very straight forward Grid connected to a DataSet. I'm doing this in **VISUAL BASIC.** *Using Telerik Winforms Q3 2013.*

Every column is a text Column, 2 of them are **Multi Column Combo Boxes**, attached to a distinct dataset which just brings the possible information. And is only intended for reference.

I want to let the user be able to key into these columns any text they want regardless if it's on the list or not.

I looked at this post http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-editors-howto-allow-end-users-to-add-items-to-dropdownlisteditor.html

But this example is just too confusing and most importantly, it saves to the ref/underlining ref dataset, which is not desirable.

How can I set up the comboboxes to allow users to enter any text they want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Multi Column Combo Boxes are working with items, these items are gotten from the data source of the  Multi Column Combo Box. So in order to allow freely typed text, the latter should be added to the data source.